# Extra space character before OS item

Tags: bug, android-app

When adding a bug report via Android app, list of specification items added to message body automatically. And for the last one (OS) extra space character is added (you can also see it in current post).

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-D802

  - OS Version: 5.0.2 (152331922a212)

Comment: Chance it's by design, to make it more prominent. Or special. Guess we'll never know.

Comment: @ShadowWizard iOS app does not have such problem. And 'yes' your link is for same question (duplicate), but that question has no answer and I can't click `That solved my problem!` button :) because it did not solve my problem.

Comment: No point leaving 100 same requests open. It's just more messy.